# CountDistinct on a range

Tags: algorithms, counting

I have a dataset with and ID and a date looking like:

```
+----+------------+
| ID |    date    |
+----+------------+
| A  | 2021-07-20 |
| B  | 2021-07-20 |
| C  | 2021-07-20 |
| A  | 2021-07-20 |
| A  | 2021-07-21 |
| C  | 2021-07-21 |
| C  | 2021-07-21 |
| B  | 2021-07-22 |
| C  | 2021-07-22 |
| D  | 2021-07-22 |
| .  | ...        |
+----+------------+
```

I have currently 123 distinct dates and few millions of ID.

Unfortunately, I am not allowed to export the ID (even if I anonymise it). I would like to know if there is a way to preprocess the data to be able to store and query the number of distinct ID on a date **range**.

For example between `2021-07-20` and `2021-07-21` there is only 3 distincts ID. I don't want to have 3 distinct on `2021-07-20` and 2 distinct on `2021-07-21` leading to 5 (I have added duplicated entries for this example but they are already dropped on my side).

I was thinking precomputing each ranges of days (123 * 123 / 2 combinations) but in term of scalability, it is not awesome (but better than nothing).

The other solution is to pivot the date in column and aggregate over all column with a count but I will have only groups of 1-2 individuals (because there is 2**123 combinations possibles of ady sequence per ID).

Any ideas is welcome and thanks for your support and time ;)

Regards,

Nicolas

Comment: Will you need to add more data rows later on?

Comment: For now, I am focusing on a fixed set of dates. If if can work for a daily update, that would be awesome but this is optionnal.

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with precomputing the answer for all ranges of dates.  You say "in term of scalability, it is not awesome" but I don't understand what you mean by this.  The time to look up the answer for a particular range sounds extremely fast.  Can you be more precise?  What are the requirement or the criteria by which you will evaluate answers?  For instance, do you have specific performance metrics?

Comment: What I meant by scalability is for N days, I'll have to compute N^2/2 ranges (of course O(N^2 is still OK mainly with small number such as 120). Now on the implementation, for each ranges, I'll have to load the dataset, filter it and count the distinct ID (I am using pyspark and I don't know if there is a way to do it more efficiently than a **for** loop).